# RISC-V/ARM64 cross-compilation of Linux kernel generates an EFI file instead of an ELF, can an ELF file be generated?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, qemu, arm64, riscv

This is the Linux kernel generated by RISC-V cross-compilation, and the file command shows that it is in EFI format

```
file arch/riscv/boot/Image
arch/riscv/boot/Image: MS-DOS executable PE32+ executable (EFI application) RISC-V 64-bit (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
```

This is the kernel on the AMD64 machine, and you can see that it is in ELF format

```
file /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-23-amd64
/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-23-amd64: Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 5.10.0-23-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) #1 SMP Debian 5.10.179-1 (2023-05-12), RO-rootFS, swap_dev 0x6, Normal VGA
```

Is it possible to control the format of the RISC-V cross-compiled kernel output file to generate ELF? I have checked and understood EFI STUB, but I am still curious if it is possible to generate RISC-V Linux kernel in ELF format? And does the `-kernel` parameter of QEMU RSIC-V support loading kernel files in ELF format?

Comment: It might be useful to explain why ELF is of value to you.  In other words, what problem is it that you're trying to solve?

Comment: I think you are looking for vmlinux file generated in the base directory. By base I mean the directory you are compiling your kernel in. The answer here explains a bit about this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74325883/9233445

Comment: EFI looks like an unneeded part here. On my risc-v SBC, for example, first there's u-boot, grouped with SBI, runs, then u-boot creates EFI environment and searches for EFI partition, finally runs EFI kernel from there. Why not simply take kernel image from normal linux root FS and run it? Probably that is the motivation -- the kernel config indeed seems to have no option to generate image instead of EFI.

Comment: What I kown: 
- QEMU RISC-V virt accepts firmware(bios) in ELF/FlatBinary format.
- QEMU RISC-V virt accepts kernels in ELF/EFI/FlatBinary format